# Does lossy decompression always generate same output?

Tags: compression, mp3, jpeg, h.264, aac

Considering lossy compression formats (for images, audio, video etc...) and given that it only operates on the same compressed input file, does the same decompression algorithm always generate the same output?
And what about different flavours of decompressors, do they generate the same output with the same input? I've read somewhere that some jpeg-decompression algorithms trade quality for speed, meaning that they wouldn't produce the same output.

So to summarize, given that we can know both the compression and decompression algorithms in use, will we be able to rely on the output always being the same. Can one get deterministic behaviour by controlling which algorithms are put to use?

Note. It doesn't necessarily have to output the original input though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the compression standard. Modern standards, such as H.264, have strict specs and reference decoders, and any compliant decoder should output bitwise exactly the same output as the reference decoder (modulo bugs of course). Older video codecs (such as MPEG-4 Part 2) don't specify the complete process in quite as much detail, so different implementations may output slightly different data (looking roughly similar but with minor differences in rounding). With inter-frame codecs, where future frames depend on earlier, such rounding errors can accumulate though.

For audio codecs, a compliant decoder mostly needs to come close to a reference signal while allowing for some implementation/rounding differences.

In most cases, the trading of quality for speed is done in the encoder, but some decoders also have options for deviating from the standards, to increase decoding speed but not outputting the exact correct image.

So it all comes down to both what codec standards you're using (whether they're written precisely enough to allow independent, bitexact implementations of them) and the actual decoder implementations.

Comment: Yeah, rounding errors, didn't think of that. But is it safe to say that the same decoder will output the exact same bitstream if run twice with the same input? Or will these inter-frame codecs you mention behave non-deterministically in this sense?

Comment: No, codecs that use inter-frames shouldn't be adding any nondeterminism per se, so in principle they should always return the same output data given the same input data. If it's a non-bitexact codec, you might get different results on different hardware though (either due to e.g. floating point rounding, or using different codepaths, e.g. SIMD, depending on the hardware's capabilities), but that might also be configurable in the decoder.

Comment: How about streamed formats? Are there any ways of predicting the endpoint bit streams before hand, or are all streamed formats constructed to take into account packet loss and data corruption?

Comment: If you mean, if one can predict what a receiver will decode - that depends very much on the kind of streaming protocol in use. Some run over TCP, where that layer will take care of any retransmissions. Protocols that run over UDP are more vulnerable, and there's a lot of different techniques involved to get some sort of reliability there (forward error correction, packet loss indication to request retransmits, etc), and in those cases it's pretty hard to guess what the receiver will get.